# Help identifying this character in a friend's shirt (Character identified: 龍)

Tags: character-identification

A friend of mine purchased a shirt with writing that may be in Chinese. Could someone help us understand what it says?

[image]

Comment: Flip the image horizontally then try again using a phone OCR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the traditional Chinese character for "**dragon**", pronounced long2 (i.e. second tone). The simplified version looks like this: 龙